# How to Import Multiple Values in custom field

Tags: mysql, csv

I want to know how to import multiple values in a custom field, I am quite familiar in using custom field for single values but for multiple values is what I am having trouble with
for example my csv contains

```
Post_ID |  Pet Size | Pet Color   <- this is the header
GS        Small      Brown
GS        Medium     White
GS        Large      Dark
CW         Small      Beige
CW         Medium     White
CW         Tiny       Black
```

My Goal is to display

```
German Shepard Available Features(GS)
      Size
       Small    - Brown
       Medium   - White
       Large    - Dark
```

Comment: I would look at firstly:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

Then I would parse your CSV into an array and use http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php to store the info as an array for the custom field key

Then you need to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php on the frontend with your get_post_meta

Comment: yes but the problem is has over  40,000 id's and parsing it would be a lot of work, is there no other way?

Comment: You may have to write a custom importer for this.. You may have to end up storing 40,000 records for one Post ID.

Comment: yes i think you got why i am trying to achieve, i guess there is no other way that to write a custom imported, do you know any reference?

Answer (score 0):

The granularity of data in your example suggests that custom field (more so one with multiple values) would be wrong choice in first place.

Think about it like this:

- only *one* dog might weight precisely `35.5`kg — that is type of data appropriate for custom field
- *multiple* dogs (or dog breeds) might be of `medium` weight — that is type of data appropriate for custom taxonomy

In either case it is preferable to handle task like this through WP API, rather than import via MySQL. 40K records is very reasonable, and your data doesn't seem problematic to process.

Comment: i figured using taxonomy but i need to display multiple data that is assigned to a single post or id, for the example you have given " The German Shepard" is 35kg & 55kg  and the size of 35kg is small and 55kg is medium, the custom field will be called weight and size but when i import it, only small & 35kg gets imported, how about the 55kg & medium, how would it be imported? or how will additional row be imported

Comment: @JPL That's the details of your import implementation. If breed is CPT and size is taxonomy then you'll need to assign multiple terms of that taxonomy to the breed as necessary. Also I meant `35.55` kg (as in precise weight, not two weights, sorry :) different decimal separator around here).

Comment: @Rasrt okay i made a screenshot for clarification, breed is not a custom post type but a custom field only < http://screencast.com/t/d9axPvPlpyS > then the output would like that as well but i will code in table style so basically i am looking to append the data in a custom field

Comment: @JPL this example is kind of completely different from your original question, so I am hesitant to advise anything without understanding of your actual use case.

Comment: i am not sure what's the difference , I only change the value but a more precise general idea would be like importing a list(thousands) of first name and last in a custom field. Let me know if you have trouble understanding my question and thanks for answering my question, I really appreciate it.